# pytorch LSTM: RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 4 cifar10 image classification

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, torch

I am implementing simple LSTM architecture to classify images in CIFAR10 dataset. It did not work out for me.

What am I doing wrong???

**Model**

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch import nn
import torchvision.datasets as dsets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# https://ashutoshtripathicom.files.wordpress.com/2021/06/rnn-vs-lstm.png?w=640
# torch.manual_seed(1)    # reproducible

# Hyper Parameters
EPOCH = 1  # train the training data n times, to save time, we just train 1 epoch
BATCH_SIZE = 64
TIME_STEP = 32  # rnn time step / image height
INPUT_SIZE = 32  # rnn input size / image width
LR = 0.01  # learning rate
DOWNLOAD_MNIST = True  # set to True if haven't download the data

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)

all_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((32, 32)), transforms.ToTensor(),
                                     transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465],
                                                          std=[0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010])])

train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, transform=all_transforms, download=True)
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, transform=all_transforms, download=True)

# Instantiate loader objects to facilitate processing
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=512, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=512, shuffle=True)


class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(  # if use nn.RNN(), it hardly learns
            input_size=INPUT_SIZE,
            hidden_size=64,  # rnn hidden unit
            num_layers=1,  # number of rnn layer
            batch_first=True,  # input & output will has batch size as 1s dimension. e.g. (batch, time_step, input_size)
        )
        self.gap = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))
        self.out = nn.Linear(64, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.rnn(x)
        x = self.gap(x)
        x = x.flatten()
        x = x.flatten(start_dim=1)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x



model = RNN()
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.cuda()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=0.005, momentum=0.9)
total_step = len(train_loader)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LR)  # optimize all cnn parameters
loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()  # the target label is not one-hotted
epochs = 20

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images = images.cuda()
        labels = labels.cuda()

        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        # torch.save(model, 'model.pt')
    print("Epochs [{}/{}], Loss: {:4f}".format(epoch + 1, epochs, loss.item()))

with torch.no_grad():
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for images, labels in train_loader:
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        outputs = model(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    print('Accuracy of the network on the {} train images: {} %'.format(50000, 100 * correct / total))
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_1/tutorials/rnn.py", line 73, in <module>
    outputs = model(images)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_1/tutorials/rnn.py", line 48, in forward
    x = self.rnn(x)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 659, in forward
    self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 605, in check_forward_args
    self.check_input(input, batch_sizes)
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/tutorials/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 198, in check_input
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: input must have 3 dimensions, got 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html?highlight=lstm#torch.nn.LSTM) for the available input shape of `nn.LSTM`.

Your `images` is the tensor of size `BxCxHxW` which can't be fed to `nn.LSTM` directly.